# How to start kubernetes job from website?

Tags: c#, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes.

I have a k8s cron job that runs once per minute and executes a C# app that checks a SQL Server table for new records and processes them.

The new records are inserted based on actions the user takes on a web page.

I want to change the triggering mechanism.
Instead of running the app every minute in k8s using a cron job, I want to instead trigger it from the website immediately after the new records have been inserted in SQL Server.

I am not finding answers on best practices for doing this.
Would I create a k8s job to execute the app, then somehow expose a URL that can be POSTed to that will trigger the job to run?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct link from "website to k8s"

Your website would need to use Javascript to communicate with a backend. That backend would have an authenticated k8s client (e.g. [`kubernetes-client/csharp`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp)) that can issue requests to the k8s api-server.

---

Regarding the actual problem, you should ideally be using [change-data-capture (CDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) from the database, not a cron job. Depending on what tools you use to capture those events, then yes, you would need some kind of route/websocket to receive updates back to the front-end.